Cannot link libstrophe with openssl 3.0
SSL_get_peer_certificate, which is used in tls_openssl.c, is deprecated starting from openssl 3.0. I'm getting undefined symbol _SSL_get1_peer_certificate error from linker trying to link it with system provided ssl.dylib (openssl version 3.2).
Interesting thing is that it links when libstrophe is compiled with openssl 1.1.1 headers. Does not compile with 3.0 headers if macro OPENSSL_NO_DEPRECATED is defined. Compiles without this macro but does not link.
Is it possible to make libstrophe work with openssl 3.0?

Your explanation isn't completely clear, but that sounds like it's doing what you told it to do: "If this macro is defined, all deprecated public symbols in all OpenSSL versions up to and including the version given by OPENSSL_API_COMPAT (or the default value given above, when OPENSSL_API_COMPAT isn't defined) will be hidden."
